# Get the offsets and position of searched terms in Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, term-vectors

While doing a search for a text in solr , I am trying to get offset for the search term in the result.
for eg :

```
q=id:123456+((description:"abcde"+document:"abcde"+author:"abcde"))&fl=id,codes&sort=service_date+desc
```

In response I want:

```
{
  "offset":"";
}
```

Currently I am manually calculating that after getting the response in the code.

I am reading on term vector (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/the-term-vector-component.html), but I am not sure about it.
If any one can guide me with any method that would be helpful .

Comment: Usually highlighting would be the way to do this, as it gives you back the terms wrapped by identifiable markers; as far as I know termvectors will not give you only information about which terms matched your query.

Comment: Currently , I get the marker em tags and use that to get the offsets , but does solr provide a better way ?

Comment: @KrishnaSharma can you use the marker em tags to get offsets in the context of the full document?